# Error in enforcePackage(name, curVersion) : The shiny package was not found in the library

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I'm trying to deploy a shiny app to shinyapps server. the app works just fine locally and when deploying using `rsconnect::deployApp()` I can see the message *Application successfully deployed to* in the console but actually on browser is not working and showing the following:

`Error in enforcePackage(name, curVersion) : The shiny package was not found in the library. Calls: local ... eval -> eval -> eval -> <Anonymous> -> enforcePackage. Execution halted`

Shiny package is loaded of course.
Also when trying to run `rsconnect::appDependencies()` the following error pop-up :
*Error in [.data.frame(deps, , "Package") : undefined columns selected*

Thank you all in advance for your help

Comment: Do you need to call `library(shiny)` in the app?

Comment: @william3031 Yes

Comment: @HediBenMustapha were you able to solve this?